# Add animation to an append element ? (SwiftUI)

Tags: animation, append, swiftui

Is it possible to add an animation to an element that is added to an array (with the .append() method) ?

Exemple : I have a button, and when I tap it, an element appear on my screen, but it pops brutally on screen, I want to add a smooth transition but how?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without any code. Still, you can try to enable animations on the top level view like this:

```
  VStack {
    Text("blah")
  }.animation(.default)
```

Comment: Simple yet very effective ! Thank you ! :)